# Search data between two dates in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss in sql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch all records between two dates from database in php. Date format is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. example 06/Dec/2016 05:56:15

I'm using following code

```
$Sdate=date_create($_GET['sdate']);
$start=date_format($Sdate,"d/M/Y H:i:s");

$Edate=date_create($_GET['edate']);
$end=date_format($Edate,"d/M/Y H:i:s");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE `customerid` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND dateandtime BETWEEN ('".$start."', '".$end."') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

But this is not working

Thank You in advance for helping me

Comment: `dateandtime BETWEEN ('".$start."', '".$end."')` should be something like `dateandtime BETWEEN '".$start."' AND  '".$end."'`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: [SQL INJECTION EVERYWHERE !!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: or just `'$start' AND '$end'` - but see about injection, parametrised queries, etc.

Comment: Did you use the above date format within the query parameter or is it the date format inside your database table? `date_create` won't work with this string format, nor does strtotime. You should use `date_create_from_format('d/M/Y H:i:s', '06/Dec/2016 05:56:15');`

instead.
 If you use this format inside your table `BETWEEN` won't work either as this format is not sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Sdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['sdate']);
$Edate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['edate']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `payments` 
WHERE `customerid` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
AND dateandtime BETWEEN '$Sdate' AND '$Edate' 
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

The correct syntax is:

```
dateField BETWEEN dateFieldLow AND dateFieldHigh
```